# Is the term 'lead head' used by astronauts?

Tags: astronauts, terminology, space-sickness

In an article on the [Space.com](https://www.space.com/1792-nauseating-news-spacesickness.html) website, the author states "Very few astronauts have what's called the 'lead head'--immune from space adaptation syndrome or space sickness."

I couldn't find any other references to this term doing basic searches.  Did astronauts, or NASA use this term?  Has this term been mentioned in any sources not connected to that article?

Comment: The term does not appear in section 3.2 IDIOMS AND COLLOQUIALISMS USED AT NASA of JSC–36207 Space Flight Technical Language  Handbook

Comment: Is that handbook available online, or at least to the general public in some form?

Comment: It's fairly short, I'll put it on my list of documents to scan and upload to archive.org. Will report back when done.

Comment: I found a pdf, no scanning required. It's online at https://ia601403.us.archive.org/24/items/spacetalk/spacetalk.pdf

Comment: Interesting reading -- looks like that list is perhaps more meant for international partners not familiar with idiomatic english.  I haven't found a whole lot in that list that is uniquely "NASA"

Comment: Oop, found it: "1.2 PURPOSE
The purpose of the Space Flight Technical Language Handbook is to provide the International
Partners (IPs) with a desk reference for communication in the NASA/JSC environments. It also
could be used as a training reference for individuals studying technical space flight language."

Comment: @Tristan yes, that is exactly what it was for. Just because you speak English as a second language doesn't mean you grok "Flight, hide one is toast, we need ayy-pee-you two cooled down ayy-sap and restarted at tame".  I don't think it was a raging success though.

Comment: I must admit, when I saw the section title and document title in your original content, I thought it was a clever joke.  Nope.  It actually exists.

Comment: Never heard the subject term, "lead head" used in this context (I was in the Office from 1996-2004, inclusive).  It was said, however, that, "You pay going up, or you pay coming back, nobody flies in Space for free."  Meaning: although there were those who never got SAS, they had an acutely rough time re-adapting to Earth after the flight...I'm aware of this being true in several situations...

Comment: @Digger Could you point me to any discussion of what was acutely rough in re-adapting to Earth after the flight, for those that didn't pay going up?

Comment: @Bob516 Not sure you would find much info on this that has been released to the public.  AFAIK, these types of data fall under the category of "private medical information."  The crewmembers so affected (afflicted?) would need to approve the release of said data.  Most astronauts I know are pretty protective of their medical records.  However, a decent search could very well uncover pertinent records that have been "sanitized."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long time, no answer, so I'll take a stab at it...please be aware that all of my "evidence," while purely anecdotal, is first hand.

I never heard the subject term, "lead head" used in this context (I was in The Office from 1996-2004, inclusive). It was frequently said, however, that, "You pay going up, or you pay coming back, nobody flies in Space for free."

**Meaning:** although there were those who never got Space Adaptation Sickness (SAS), many (if not all) of these seemingly lucky folks had an acutely rough time re-adapting to Earth after the flight...I'm aware of this being true in several situations (manifesting itself in vomiting and/or dehydration severe enough to require IV transmission of fluids).